# Can I force a rerender with setState even if the data hasn't changed? My GUI won't update?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, normalizr

So the problem I'm having right now is on first click, my GUI re-renders.  But on second click, it does not re-render. I believe it's because I am not updating the state of "graphicLayers" which my render is binding through the "graphicLayers.map".  That's my theory anyway (even though it works on first click?  but not the 2nd click or anything after).

I tried forcing an setState update of graphicLayers, but it doesn't seem to be working. Like this:

```
let graphicLayersCopy = Object.assign([], this.state.graphicLayers);
this.setState({graphicLayers: graphicLayersCopy});
```

but that's not working. I know through the debugger that it's setting the data correctly, and if I refresh (it saves state and reloads the state), the GUI is then rendered correctly.

Is there anyway I can force a re-render of a variable some how even if it doesn't change value?

constructor

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      graphicLayers: [id1, id2, id3],
      graphicLayersById: {
        id1: { ... },
        id2: { ... },
        id3: { ... }
      }

    this.addLayerClick = this.addLayerClick.bind(this);
};
```

render

```
render() {
    return (        
    <div>
      {this.state.graphicLayers.map((id) =>
        <GraphicLayer addLayerClick={this.addLayerClick.bind(this)} />
      )}
    </div>
    );
   }
```

addLayerClick

```
addLayerClick() {
  ... change some property in graphicLayersById dictionary ...
  self.setState({ graphicLayersById: newDataHere });
}
```

EDIT: I found the problem on my end, and it's not exactly shown here.

So my addLayerClick() actually calls another functions that is listening to a call and it sets the state inside.  it's weird because the setState gets called in the callback function, but i got it to work by putting the setState in the addLayerClick() itself.. still dont know why this doens't work but i will upvote all of you at least

listenFunction() {

```
let self = this;

this.firebaseWrapper.storage.on('graphicLayersById', function (save) {
  if (save) {
    self.setState({ graphicLayersById: save });  // FOR SOME REASON THIS DOESN'T UPDATE THE GUI THE 2nd CLICK.  The data is correct though and I see it going here on a breakpoint, but GUI won't update unless I setState in the actual button
  }
  else {
    self.setState({ graphicLayersById: undefined });
  }
});
```

}

Comment: .bind(this) is written twice.

Comment: @TreefishZhang hey thanks for the comment.  i actually added that there when i found the problem hoping that it would work.. i removed it though just based on your comment and left the one in the constructor, but still same problem unfortunately

Comment: I have used window.location.reload() to force rerender, but it is expensive:entire page is repainted.

Comment: "Is there anyway I can force a re-render of a variable some how even if it doesn't change value?" calling `this.setState({})` will cause the render function to be invoked without changing any values on the state object...

Comment: This link says that you have to have state set before you render, and it is not right to do setState inside render(): https://medium.com/javascript-scene/setstate-gate-abc10a9b2d82

Comment: On 'still dont know why this doens't work': My hunch is that you should do setState in a handleAddLayerClick() function in the wrapper component of your said component and then pass the function down to your said component where you do not do setState again, just render().

Comment: @TreefishZhang i actually found the problem thanks to a friend.  My GraphicLayer component was actually taking the props received and storing it to the state of the GraphicLayer component.  So the setState i've been talking about was on the home component and wasn't rendering the GrahpicLayer state.. which was stupid in the first place.  i removed the state entirely from the GraphicLayer component and just worked with the props (since i was passing in the click function from my home component) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: the only mystery though is why setState in my home component was rendering it....

Comment: Oh so I take it that 'home' component is the parent of 'GraphicLayer'? That would make sense: when state changes via setState in 'home', the changes pass down to the child component 'GraphicLayer' , and get rendered. It is the obligation of React to rerender when props changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `addLayerClick()` you're only updating `graphicLayersById`, but rendering depends on **`graphicLayers`**. You should be updating the `graphicLayers` state in `addLayerClick()` as well.

```
addLayerClick() {
  this.setState({
    graphicLayers: ...
    graphicLayersById: ....
  });
}
```

On a side note, you shouldn't bind methods inside `render()` since that creates a brand new function on every render (and could impact performance). Instead of

```
<GraphicLayer addLayerClick={this.addLayerClick.bind(this)} />
```

do

```
<GraphicLayer addLayerClick={this.addLayerClick} />
```

and leave the binding in your constructor (the way you already have).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you have bound the `addLayerClick()` function to the component, so you can use `this` instead of `self`

You should revise your code like this: (there are about 2 changes)

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      graphicLayers: [id1, id2, id3],
      graphicLayersById: {
        id1: { ... },
        id2: { ... },
        id3: { ... }
      }
    // don't need to bind here anymore, since you bind it in the click
    //this.addLayerClick = this.addLayerClick.bind(this);
};

addLayerClick() {
  //... change some property in graphicLayersById dictionary ...
  // just use 'this' here
  this.setState({ graphicLayersById: newDataHere });

  // the below line is NOT recommended, which is force the component to update
  // this.forceUpdate(); // this line will update the component even though there's no change 
}
```

If this doesn't work yet, please post here how you handle `onCLick` function in the child component, and also post some errors if any, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hope these two possible way will reder your view

```
this.setState({graphicLayersById: newDataHere} , ()=>{
console.log(this.state.graphicLayersById);
});
```

OR

```
var update = require('react-addons-update');
    var graphicLayers = update(this.state, {
            graphicLayersById: {$set: newDataHere}
        });
        this.setState(graphicLayers);
```